# Blazor creating database context

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, dbcontext, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

I'm tidying some old Blazor code after an upgrade to .NET 6 and running into some issues with dbcontext & Identity.  As as rule of thumb is the following the correct approach?

In Blazor WASM, create db context via dependency injection in DAL service classes (in the Server project via Web API access).

In Blazor Server, create db context from a Factory in DAL service classes after injecting an IDbContextFactory.

Comment: Yes, but you should really use the factory and "unit of work" principles in both situations.  I'm assuming you've read the Ms-Docs second on DB Contexts in Blazor?

Comment: Hi, yes I've read everything I can find.  But there's seems to be a lack of a definitive best practice approach for each case.

Comment: That's because there's no such thing as a definitive "Best Practice": projects are too varied.  I have a demo template that shows you how to build your data layers to service both WASM and Server projects - [it's here](https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo) but please don't take it as anything other that my practice.   There's also Hassan Habib's [The Standard](https://github.com/hassanhabib/The-Standard) that is about the best you'll get to one person's definition of best practice.  My demo is loosely based on it.